# Promise { <pending> } returned in spite of async/await being used

Tags: javascript

Here is my initial attempt:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
...
const getUserData = async function() {
    return await fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}

const usersStore = getUserData();
console.log(usersStore)
```

I get the result: `Promise { <pending> }`

Confused that I still got a Promise pending, I tried this:

```
const usersStore = getUserData()
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => json);
```

but got the same result, so I tried this:

```
const getUserData = function() {
    const url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const result = fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json)
            .then((json) => json);
        return resolve(result);
    });
}
```

Still same result.

The only thing that worked was an IIFE, but I didn't want to use that just to get my data.

Comment: `const usersStore = getUserData();
console.log(usersStore)` You cannot retrieve a value which is retrieved asynchronously, synchronosly. You must wait for the Promise to resolve.

Comment: First of all, `await` in `return await ...` is unnecessary. As far as the question is concerned,  you can access the data from the API inside a callback function of `then()` or inside an `async` function after awaiting the call to `getUserData()`

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I think I was right on the initial attempt, I did everything right but I didn't realize that I needed to continue to use multiple thens to get the data.  For example, getUserData().then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))

Comment: Better yet, this would have worked too:

```

const usersStore = getUserData()
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));

```